# how to use draggable and click separately in kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, draggable, kineticjs

how to use draggable and click on same node in kineticjs? when using draggable then a click event fires also after drag.

in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/matobaa/LZ5tt/

Here is the code...

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container', width: 640, height: 480
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var oval = new Kinetic.Ellipse({
  x: 100, y: 100, radius: 50, stroke: 'red',
  draggable: true,
});
oval.on('click', function(evt) {
  alert("clicked!"); // Will not be triggered after drag
})
layer.add(oval);
stage.add(layer);
```

I'm using kineticjs 4.4.1. please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to detect drag state. Es:

```
var indrag = false;
oval.on('dragstart', function(evt){
    indrag = true;
});
oval.on('dragend', function(evt){
    indrag = false;
});
```

and then:

```
oval.on('click', function(evt) {
    if (!indrag){
        alert("clicked!"); // Will not be triggered after drag
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking the current event functioning through a variable value.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LZ5tt/4/

```
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container', width: 640, height: 480
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var oval = new Kinetic.Ellipse({
        x: 100, y: 100, radius: 50, stroke: 'red',
      draggable: true,
    });
    var drag = false;
    oval.on('dragstart', function(event){
        drag = true;
    });
    oval.on('dragend', function(event){
        drag = false;
    });
    oval.on('click', function(event) {
        if (!drag){
            alert("I'm clicked!");
        }
    })
    layer.add(oval);
    stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some useful tip as for KineticJS version 5.1.0.

In case of detecting clicks over a Kinetic Stage, you might be experiencing that after finishing a drag on a shape, the click event on the stage will fire.

What I suggest is to set a *control* variable to "true" inside the *dragstart*; and then, check that variable inside the click event triggered, you set it to "false" and then *return* to exit the code block.
This way you will not prevent the click event, but nothing will happen as it is handled.

Allow me to borrow some code from the answer above:

```
var indrag = false;

oval.on('dragstart', function(evt){
    indrag = true;
});
oval.on('dragend', function(evt){

});

stage.on('click', function(evt) {
    if (indrag){
        indrag = false;
        return;
    }

    // else, it is a valid click, then do what you need to do...
})
```