# Draggable figure collision with random static figures

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs, collision

I have many static squares randomly on a canvas. Is there any way that these squares can detect when another `draggable` figure collide between them and print the 'name' attribute of the `rect`?

Here's the code (also available in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpincheiraa/MLque/15/))

```
var arrowMode = true;

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    height: 400,
    width: 800
});

var arrowsLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(arrowsLayer);

$(stage.getContainer()).on('click',function(e){
    if(arrowMode){

        arrowMode=false;

        var x = stage.getMousePosition().x;
        var y = stage.getMousePosition().y;

        for(var i=0;i<6;i++){

            //Rects will be collide for a circle
            var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                name:'rect'+(i+1),
                x: i<3? x + (i)*60:x + (i-3)*60,
                y: i<3? y : y +60,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                fill:'black'
            });

            arrowsLayer.add(rect);
        }

        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            draggable: true,
            stroke: "black",
            fill: "#0FF30F",
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 10,
            x:x+400,
            y:y+100
        });

    arrowsLayer.add(circle);  
    stage.add(arrowsLayer);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting question.

Let's [stand on the shoulders of giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) by using this SO question: [KineticJS - update text layer with new mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128431/kineticjs-update-text-layer-with-new-mouse-position) and this SO question: [how to use draggable and click separately in kineticjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904712/how-to-use-draggable-and-click-separately-in-kineticjs)

Now the only thing we have to do is get the coordinates of the squares, the coordinates of the mouse and then make a simple switch statement to output the text as desired.

### The Code

To get the coordinates of the squares (soft coded), I use a two-dimensional array:

```
var poss = new Array(6);
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    poss[i] = new Array(2);
}
```

Now when the user first clicks the canvas and the squares are generated, I append their coordinates to the array:

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){

      var posX = i<3? x + (i)*60:x + (i-3)*60;
      var posY = i<3? y : y +60;

      poss[i][0] = posX;
      poss[i][1] = posY;

      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
      name:'rect'+(i+1),
      x: posX,
      y: posY,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      fill:'black'
   });
```

Now I need to detect when the green dot is being dragged and then launch a function which checks for collisions.

To detect if the green dot is being dragged, I use `dragstart` and `dragend`:

```
circle.on('dragstart', function(e){
    indrag = true;
});

circle.on('dragend', function(e){
    indrag = false;
});


$(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (e) {
   if (indrag)
   {            
     checkCollision(e);
   }
});
```

Now all I need to do is define the function `checkCollision(e)` which iterates over all the coordinates of the squares (saved in the array) to check for collisions:

```
function checkCollision(event) {

  var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
  var mouseX = parseInt(pos.x);
  var mouseY = parseInt(pos.y);

  $("#coordinates").replaceWith("<div id='coordinates'>X-axis: "+mouseX+"<br />Y-axis: "+mouseY+"</div>");

  $("#inSquare").replaceWith("<div id='inSquare'>Nothing is happening</div>");

  //check if collision with squares
  for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++)
  {
     if (mouseX >= poss[k][0] && mouseX <= (poss[k][0]+50) && mouseY >= poss[k][1] && mouseY <= (poss[k][1]+50))
     {   
         $("#inSquare").replaceWith("<div id='inSquare'>You have just dragged the green dot in square number " +(k+1)+"</div>");
     }
  }

}
```

### Demo

You can find a working example of this implementation [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wKrYx/).

### The Limitations

Note two important things:

- I use the mouse-coordinates to check for collisions; not the width of the circle. If you want to use the width of the circle, you can do so by using the radius (e.g. instead of `mouseX` use `(mouseX + widthCircle)` where you define `widthCircle` in some variable) of the circle.
- Some of my code is redundant (I define some variables twice). Hence you can still shorten my code if you so desire.

I hope that answers your question. Good luck!

### Update

To display specified name attributes, I would recommend to keep your code clean and use a `switch` statement like so:

```
var name;
switch (k)
{
   case 0: name = "I'm in the upper left";                   break;
   case 1: name = "I'm more awesome than the other squares"; break;
   case 2: name = "I'm a black square";                      break;
   case 3: name = "I'm in the bottom left";                  break;
   case 4: name = "I like coffee";                           break;
   case 5: name = "Nanos gigantum humeris insidentes";       break;
}

$("#inSquare").replaceWith("<div id='inSquare'>"+name+"</div>");
```

You can find an implementation of that code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tJUw4/).